# multiple /home mountpoints

Tags: mount, home-directory, raid, mountpoint

I have 5 hard drives 1.5TB and 4-750's. What I want to do is make the 4-750's into a raid10. I already have a `/home` mountpoint on the 1.5TB drive.

I want to use the raid as DATA only no OS stuff at all. This will be storing movies and music for the network DLNA server/PLEX.  If I mount the raid10 as `/home`, will all the data go to the raid drives then fill up the 1.5TB /home mount point, or will the system combine the two?

What would be the best thing to do?

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit is installed and working great.

P.S. I don't even care a single thing about Windows any more so that will not be an issue.

```
*-disk                  
   description: ATA Disk
   product: ST31500341AS
   vendor: Seagate
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: CC1H
   serial: 9VS0M7FN
   size: 1397GiB (1500GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000762a6

*-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: SAMSUNG HD753LJ
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sdb
   version: 1AA0
   serial: S13UJDWQ401868
   size: 698GiB (750GB)
   configuration: ansiversion=5

*-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: SAMSUNG HD753LJ
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sdc
   version: 1AA0
   serial: S13UJ1KQ701933
   size: 698GiB (750GB)
   configuration: ansiversion=5

  *-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: ST3750640AS
   vendor: Seagate
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sdd
   version: 3.AF
   serial: 5QD3ZR86
   size: 698GiB (750GB)
   configuration: ansiversion=5

*-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: ST3750640AS
   vendor: Seagate
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sde
   version: 3.AF
   serial: 5QD29GWD
   size: 698GiB (750GB)
   configuration: ansiversion=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not mount two things in the same directory.  To be more precise, the most recently mounted one will be the one that shows up, and whatever files were there before will be hidden underneath and not accessible while the second one is still mounted.

Either mount the raid10 in its own directory, such as /home/yourname/raid10, or if you want to actually move the home directory there, then mount it somewhere else, such as under /media or /mnt, and run `sudo cp -ax /home /path/to/drive` to copy everything in /home to the new drive, then rename the old home directory with `sudo mv /home /oldhome`, and finally edit /etc/fstab with `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and change the mount point to the new drive.  You can look up the UUID of the new drive with the `sudo blkid` command.  After a reboot, it should be using the new drive, which you can verify with the `df` command, and you can safely remove the old home dir.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. this is exactly why i love ubuntu and the community that use it.